# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'player_id' cannot be null

Tags: laravel

I have this error when I try to add data. I have 2 tables on my database, the (players) table and the (stats) table which are connected with the "player_id" being the foreign key to the players table.

players table:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZgbY.png)

stats table:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcmbT.png)

StatsController:

```
public function index(){
    $stats = Stats::all();
    return view('stats', ['stats' => $stats]);
}

public function addstats(){
    if($this->request->method() == 'POST'){
        $alert = request() -> validate([
            'points' => 'required|numeric',
            'average_points' => 'required|numeric',
            'games' => 'required|numeric',
            'duration' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);

        $stats = new Stats;
        $stats->player_id = $this->request->id;
        $stats->points = $this->request->get('points');
        $stats->average_points = $this->request->get('average_points');
        $stats->games = $this->request->get('games');
        $stats->duration = $this->request->get('duration');
        if($stats -> save()){
            echo 'Success';
        }
    }
    return view('addstats', ['player_id' => $this->request->player_id]);
}

public function editstats(Stats $stats){
    if($this->request->method() == 'POST'){
        $alert = request() -> validate([
            'points' => 'required|numeric',
            'average_points' => 'required|numeric',
            'games' => 'required|numeric',
            'duration' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);

        $stats->player_id = $this->request->id;
        $stats->fullname = $this->request->get('points');
        $stats->age = $this->request->get('average_points');
        $stats->height = $this->request->get('games');
        $stats->weight = $this->request->get('duration');
        if($stats -> save()){
            return redirect('stats/');
        }
    }
    return view('editstats', ['stats' => $stats]);
}

public function destroy(Stats $stats){
    $stats->delete();
    return redirect('stats/');
}
```

addstats blade php:

```
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <form action="{{route('addstats')}}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$player_id}}">
            <p>Overall Points:</p>
            <input type="number" name="points" class="form-control" value="{{Request::old('points')}}" required>
            <p style="color: red">@error('points') {{$message}} @enderror</p>
            <p>Average points per game:</p>
            <input type="number" name="average_points" class="form-control" value="{{Request::old('average_points')}}" required>
            <p style="color: red">@error('average_points') {{$message}} @enderror</p>
            <p>Games:</p>
            <input type="number" name="games" class="form-control" value="{{Request::old('games')}}" required>
            <p style="color: red">@error('games') {{$message}} @enderror</p>
            <p>Duration:</p>
            <input type="number" name="duration" class="form-control" value="{{Request::old('duration')}}" required>
            <p style="color: red">@error('duration') {{$message}} @enderror</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
@endsection
```

my Routes:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', [PlayersController::class, 'index']);
    Route::post('/addplayer', [PlayersController::class, 'addplayer'])->name('addplayer');
    Route::get('/addplayer', [PlayersController::class, 'addplayer'])->name('addplayer');
    Route::get('/editplayer/{players}', [PlayersController::class, 'editplayer'])->name('editplayer');
    Route::post('/editplayer/{players}', [PlayersController::class, 'editplayer'])->name('editplayer');
    Route::get('/destroy/{players}', [PlayersController::class, 'destroy'])->name('destroy');
    Route::get('/stats/{player_id?}', [StatsController::class, 'index']);
    Route::post('/addstats', [StatsController::class, 'addstats'])->name('addstats');
    Route::get('/addstats', [StatsController::class, 'addstats'])->name('addstats');
    Route::get('/editstats/{stats?}', [StatsController::class, 'editstats'])->name('editstats');
    Route::post('/editstats/{stats?}', [StatsController::class, 'editstats'])->name('editstats');
    Route::get('/destroy/{stats?}', [StatsController::class, 'destroy'])->name('destroy');
});

class Stats extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'stats';

    protected $fillable = [
        'player_id','points','average_points','games','duration'
     ];
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `Stats` model as well or confirm if the `player_id` is a fill-able field?

Comment: Seems to me like your `$stats->player_id` is not being assigned a value correctly.

Comment: You use `$this->request->get(...)` for all the other values but not for `id`?

Comment: bc I want the player_id to show in the id of the player in the players table

Comment: You use `$this->request->get('points')` to get the "points" value. Why do you use `$this->request->id;` instead of also using `->get()`? Like `$this->request->get('id');`

Comment: first even if I do what you said I still get the same error, second as I said I don't want the user to type the player_id but the player_id to be the the same as the players' table id

Comment: @brombeer `$request->id` and `$request->get('id')` will both obtain the element with the key `id` from the `Request` object (assuming it is present).

Comment: @AgimGjini You need to check the value of `id` from your `$request`, does it exist, is it valid? Do some debugging.

Comment: @Peppermintology Oh, didn't know that, always used `->get()`. Thanks

Comment: dont use `get` use `input` ... there is a reason Laravel added the `input` method and doesn't use the `get` method of Request ... https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L348 ... https://asklagbox.com/blog/illuminate-request#you-dont-get-it